# Flutter: Bad state Error: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Flutter and getting this issue.

Trying to develop a social media app which includes a chat feature. However, it says DocumentSnapshot is not exist.

Of course I understood that one thing is missing, it is clear. But I couldn't understand what is that missing thing and how to solve it.

I examined a lot of posts about this but I couldn't solve my issue. There is no misspelling between Cloud Firestore and my code. I couldn't understand am I missing key or something like this?

[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrmWq.png)

Sometimes it also can not upload the profile picture of person.
Here are my codes,

Thanks for helping.

I got this error when I try to type a message:

```
class Conversation extends StatefulWidget {


final String userId;
  final String chatId;

  const Conversation({required this.userId, required this.chatId});

  @override
  _ConversationState createState() => _ConversationState();
}

class _ConversationState extends State<Conversation> {
  FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
  TextEditingController messageController = TextEditingController();
  bool isFirst = false;
  String? chatId;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    scrollController.addListener(() {
      focusNode.unfocus();
    });
    print(widget.chatId);
    if (widget.chatId == 'newChat') {
      isFirst = true;
    }
    chatId = widget.chatId;

    messageController.addListener(() {
      if (focusNode.hasFocus && messageController.text.isNotEmpty) {
        setTyping(true);
      } else if (!focusNode.hasFocus ||
          (focusNode.hasFocus && messageController.text.isEmpty)) {
        setTyping(false);
      }
    });
  }

  setTyping(typing) {
    //here
    UserViewModel viewModel =
        Provider.of<UserViewModel>(context, listen: false);
    viewModel.setUser();
    //here
    var user = Provider.of<UserViewModel>(context, listen: false).user;
    Provider.of<ConversationViewModel>(context, listen: false)
        .setUserTyping(widget.chatId, user, typing);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    UserViewModel viewModel =
        Provider.of<UserViewModel>(context, listen: false);
    viewModel.setUser();
    var user = Provider.of<UserViewModel>(context, listen: true).user;
    return Consumer<ConversationViewModel>(
        builder: (BuildContext context, viewModel, Widget? child) {
      return Scaffold(
        key: viewModel.scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.keyboard_backspace,
            ),
          ),
          elevation: 0.0,
          titleSpacing: 0,
          title: buildUserName(),
        ),
        body: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Flexible(
                child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: messageListStream(widget.chatId),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      //snapshot.hasData
                      //print(snapshot.data);
                      print(viewModel);
                      List messages = snapshot.data!.docs;
                      viewModel.setReadCount(
                          widget.chatId, user, messages.length);
                      return ListView.builder(
                        controller: scrollController,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                        itemCount: messages.length,
                        reverse: true,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          Message message = Message.fromJson(
                            messages.reversed.toList()[index].data(),
                          );
                          print(message.content);
                          print(message.senderUid);
                          print(message.time);
                          print(message.type);
                          return ChatBubble(
                            message: '${message.content}',
                            time: message.time!,
                            isMe: message.senderUid == user!.uid,
                            type: message.type!,
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    } else {
                      return Center(child: circularProgress(context));
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: BottomAppBar(
                  elevation: 10.0,
                  child: Container(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 100.0),
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            CupertinoIcons.photo_on_rectangle,
                            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () => showPhotoOptions(viewModel, user),
                        ),
                        Flexible(
                          child: TextField(
                            controller: messageController,
                            focusNode: focusNode,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15.0,
                              color:
                                  Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6!.color,
                            ),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                              enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              hintText: "Type your message",
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Theme.of(context)
                                    .textTheme
                                    .headline6!
                                    .color,
                              ),
                            ),
                            maxLines: null,
                          ),
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Ionicons.send,
                            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (messageController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                              sendMessage(viewModel, user);
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  _buildOnlineText(
    var user,
    bool typing,
  ) {
    if (user.isOnline) {
      if (typing) {
        return "typing...";
      } else {
        return "online";
      }
    } else {
      return 'last seen ${timeago.format(user.lastSeen.toDate())}';
    }
  }

  buildUserName() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: usersRef.doc('${widget.userId}').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
              snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot<Object?>;
          UserModel user = UserModel.fromJson(
            documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>,
          );
          return InkWell(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                  child: Hero(
                    tag: user.email!,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 25.0,
                      backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                        '${user.photoUrl}',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        '${user.username}',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 15.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                      StreamBuilder(
                        stream: chatRef.doc('${widget.chatId}').snapshots(),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            DocumentSnapshot? snap =
                                snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot<Object?>;
                            Map? data = snap.data() as Map<dynamic, dynamic>?;
                            Map? usersTyping = data?['typing'] ?? {};
                            return Text(
                              _buildOnlineText(
                                user,
                                usersTyping![widget.userId] ?? false,
                              ),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                fontSize: 11,
                              ),
                            );
                          } else {
                            return SizedBox();
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            onTap: () {},
          );
        } else {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
  }

  showPhotoOptions(ConversationViewModel viewModel, var user) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(10.0),
        ),
      ),
      builder: (context) {
        return Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: Text("Camera"),
              onTap: () {
                sendMessage(viewModel, user, imageType: 0, isImage: true);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("Gallery"),
              onTap: () {
                sendMessage(viewModel, user, imageType: 1, isImage: true);
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  sendMessage(ConversationViewModel viewModel, var user,
      {bool isImage = false, int? imageType}) async {
    String msg;
    if (isImage) {
      msg = await viewModel.pickImage(
        source: imageType!,
        context: context,
        chatId: widget.chatId,
      );
    } else {
      msg = messageController.text.trim();
      messageController.clear();
    }

    Message message = Message(
      content: '$msg',
      senderUid: user?.uid,
      type: isImage ? MessageType.IMAGE : MessageType.TEXT,
      time: Timestamp.now(),
    );

    if (msg.isNotEmpty) {
      if (isFirst) {
        print("FIRST");
        String id = await viewModel.sendFirstMessage(widget.userId, message);
        setState(() {
          isFirst = false;
          chatId = id;
        });
      } else {
        viewModel.sendMessage(
          widget.chatId,
          message,
        );
      }
    }
  }

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> messageListStream(String documentId) {
    return chatRef
        .doc(documentId)
        .collection('messages')
        .orderBy('time')
        .snapshots();
  }
}
```

Also here is the ViewModel codes if I did something wrong here:

```
class ConversationViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  ChatService chatService = ChatService();
  bool uploadingImage = false;
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  File? image;

  sendMessage(String chatId, Message message) {
    chatService.sendMessage(
      message,
      chatId,
    );
  }

  Future<String> sendFirstMessage(String recipient, Message message) async {
    String newChatId = await chatService.sendFirstMessage(
      message,
      recipient,
    );

    return newChatId;
  }

  setReadCount(String chatId, var user, int count) {
    chatService.setUserRead(chatId, user, count);
  }

  setUserTyping(String chatId, var user, bool typing) {
    chatService.setUserTyping(chatId, user, typing);
  }

  pickImage({int? source, BuildContext? context, String? chatId}) async {
    PickedFile? pickedFile = source == 0
        ? await picker.getImage(
            source: ImageSource.camera,
          )
        : await picker.getImage(
            source: ImageSource.gallery,
          );

    if (pickedFile != null) {
      CroppedFile? croppedFile = await ImageCropper().cropImage(
        sourcePath: pickedFile.path,
        aspectRatioPresets: [
          CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio3x2,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9
        ],
        uiSettings: [
          AndroidUiSettings(
            toolbarTitle: 'Crop image',
            toolbarColor: Theme.of(context!).appBarTheme.backgroundColor,
            toolbarWidgetColor: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
            initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
            lockAspectRatio: false,
          ),
          IOSUiSettings(
            minimumAspectRatio: 1.0,
          ),
        ],
      );

      Navigator.of(context).pop();

      if (croppedFile != null) {
        uploadingImage = true;
        image = File(croppedFile.path);
        notifyListeners();
        showInSnackBar("Uploading image...", context);
        String imageUrl = await chatService.uploadImage(image!, chatId!);
        return imageUrl;
      }
    }
  }

  void showInSnackBar(String value, context) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar();
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text(value),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the ChatService code:

```
class ChatService {
  FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

  sendMessage(Message message, String chatId) async {
    //will send message to chats collection with the usersId
    await chatRef.doc("$chatId").collection("messages").add(message.toJson());
    //will update "lastTextTime" to the last time a text was sent
    await chatRef.doc("$chatId").update({"lastTextTime": Timestamp.now()});
  }

  Future<String> sendFirstMessage(Message message, String recipient) async {
    User user = firebaseAuth.currentUser!;
    DocumentReference ref = await chatRef.add({
      'users': [recipient, user.uid],
    });
    await sendMessage(message, ref.id);
    return ref.id;
  }

  Future<String> uploadImage(File image, String chatId) async {
    Reference storageReference =
        storage.ref().child("chats").child(chatId).child(uuid.v4());
    UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(image);
    await uploadTask.whenComplete(() => null);
    String imageUrl = await storageReference.getDownloadURL();
    return imageUrl;
  }

//determine if a user has read a chat and updates how many messages are unread
  setUserRead(String chatId, User user, int count) async {
    DocumentSnapshot snap = await chatRef.doc(chatId).get();
    Map reads = snap.get('reads') ?? {};
    reads[user.uid] = count;
    await chatRef.doc(chatId).update({'reads': reads});
  }

//determine when a user has start typing a message
  setUserTyping(String chatId, User user, bool userTyping) async {
    DocumentSnapshot snap = await chatRef.doc(chatId).get();
    Map typing = snap.get('typing');
    typing[user.uid] = userTyping;
    await chatRef.doc(chatId).update({
      'typing': typing,
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: first thing I noticed is that you're not calling `notifyListeners()` at the end of the viewModel's methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I also noticed that I'm using get() method for typing. It can be a reason to this error. But I don't know what to change these lines: '  setUserTyping(String chatId, User user, bool userTyping) async {
    DocumentSnapshot snap = await chatRef.doc(chatId).get();
    Map typing = snap.get('typing') ?? {};
    typing[user.uid] = userTyping;
    await chatRef.doc(chatId).update({
      'typing': typing,
    });
  }
}'

Comment: bad state is thrown whenever Dart tries to access an element inside a List object which is empty. \

Comment: can you provide snippet code of `ChatService()` class ?

Comment: related similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/73816043/4571931 . Hope it helps.

Comment: @pmatatias here i added my ChatService code at the end of my question. I guess the error is because of 'DocumentSnapshot snap = await chatRef.doc(chatId).get();' line. How can I fix this?

Comment: @GökçenazAkyol , im not sure but maybe you can try to change it `nullable`  value.
`DocumentSnapshot? snap = await...`  with question mark, snap will nullable.

Comment: if you got different error, plz let me know

Comment: @pmatatias I tried and unfortunately got the same error.